# How to inject EntityManager in a MDB which is configured in ejb-jar.xml

Tags: jpa, ejb, weblogic12c, message-driven-bean

I have demo application with JPA 2.1 and weblogic 12.1.3 deployment works fine and am able to get EntityManager which is annotated on the stateless bean.

I have application where I have ejb-jar.xml, on this file we have configured all MDB and session beans, Note: application is not using annotation.

And ejb-jar.xml uses http://java.sun.com/dtd/ejb-jar_2_0.dtd(ejb 2), but our application is running on weblogic 12.1.3. On this configuration, I tried to get EntityManager with the help of annotation in MDB, but am getting null object.

Question.
1. Is it possible to annotate EntityManager, with above configuration.
2. If not possible what are alternative ways. meaning I need to move all the configuration of ejb-jar.xml to annotation.

Thanks
Daya